# Why does C# prefer type alias instead of type name?

Tags: c#, .net, types

When .NET was created back in 2001-2002, they have created the .NET types (String, Int64, Boolean) and also created the type aliases (string,long,bool).
The official Microsoft reason for this was to lure and help c/c++ programmers to transition to the new C#.
I remember this because I was in the audience when they announced .NET and explained about the types.

So 20 years later, .NET still prefers the aliases, even when I specify the type Names.
For example if I write `List<Tuple<String,DateTime,Int64>> l = new`, this will autocomplete to `List<Tuple<string, DateTime, long>>()`.

```
List<Tuple<String,DateTime,Int64>> l = new List<Tuple<string, DateTime, long>>()
```

Is there a reason for this preference?
What happened to the [Color Coding](https://science.jrank.org/programming/Color_Coding.html) concept ?

Comment: "The official Microsoft reason for this was to lure and help c/c++ programmers to transition to the new C#." - do you have a citation for this?

Comment: @Dai No, I am the author of this statement. They actually said this on stage when announcing .NET.

Comment: @Dai I remember this because back then in the audience I said to myself: what a stupid thing this is, because no way that type names int vs Int32 will cause a c++ dev to turn away from a programming language. Am I correct? Who can say that I am wrong?

Comment: `Is there a reason for this preference?` There are two options. They needed to pick one. They picked the safest one (since you can define your own `String` class and thus cause surprises, but you can't fiddle with the `string` keyword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now an IDE preference (and has been since VS2008 IIRC). If you change your C# Text Editor settings to prefer "Framework type names" instead of "Predefined types" (C#'s built-in aliases) then it will use the full type-names whenever it generates or reformats code.

[image]

However there are plenty of bugs and gaps in its coverage - I prefer using type-names myself and there are cases where the IDE will still use the aliases. YMMV.

### As for "why?"...

> The official Microsoft reason for this was to lure and help c/c++ programmers to transition to the new C#.

I can't say I've heard or seen this (but not heard a refutation or denial either). I assumed it was just something that C# inherited from using C-style syntax (like how Java and Swift also have the same keywords).

Note that C#, unlike Visual Basic, doesn't have implicit imports, so if you want to use `Int32` or `String` instead of `int` and `string` respectively then you need to have `using System;` in every file. Some people just don't want to do that.

Comment: @realPro The same settings can also be set in `.editorConfig`